# How can I get a handlebars.js minimized precompiled template using handlebars as a library?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

Using handlebars as a command line tool I can do this:

```
handlebars mytemplate.hbs -m
```

And the output is a precompiled template, where `-m` indicates that it should be minimized.
Using handlebars as a library from a node.js file I can do this:

```
var precompiled = Handlebars.precompile(mytemplate)
```

Question is, which is the equivalent to `-m` when calling `Handlebars.precompile` method?

Comment: Handlebars cli uses [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) for minification. I think it's impossible to get minified output of precompile method itself, and you should minify it manually by requiring `uglify` and calling `uglify.minify`.

Comment: You are right, looking at handlebars bin command code, minification is done after calling handlebars.precompile. Could you please answer the question so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because of Handlebars cli such an interface to Handlebars lib itself and it [uses](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/precompiler.js#L136) [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) for minification.

But you can do that manually by requiring uglify and call `uglify.minify` like Handlebars cli do:

```
var uglify = require('uglify');
var precompiled = Handlebars.precompile(mytemplate);
precompiled = uglify.minify(precompiled);
```